# IntelliJ: "java connot find symbol class" when class is in same package

Tags: intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I have 2 classes in the same package:

```
com.infinity.sparkler.SparkDevice
com.infinity.sparkler.SparkCloudSession
```

`SparkDevice` uses `SparkCloudSession` but the IntelliJ compiler all of a sudden can't find `SparkCloudSession`. It was working fine and then seemingly randomly stopped. The real-time compiler still works and thinks everything is fine.

```
Error:(5, 13) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SparkCloudSession
  location: class com.infinity.sparkler.SparkDevice
Error:(13, 35) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SparkCloudSession
  location: class com.infinity.sparkler.SparkDevice
Error:(9, 23) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SparkCloudSession
  location: class com.infinity.sparkler.SparkDevice
```

The two classes in question can be found here (along with the whole project):
http://github.com/grantwest/Sparkler/tree/master/src/main/java/com/infinity/sparkler

Things I have tried:

- Made sure the right folders have been marked as Sources Root & Test Sources Root
- Deleted all of the binaries and tried to re-compile.
- Invalidated the IntelliJ cache and rebooted my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow a couple lines made it into my .idea/compiler.xml

```
<excludeFromCompile>
<file url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/src/main/java/com/infinity/sparkler/SparkCloudSession.java" />
</excludeFromCompile>
```

I closed the project, deleted compiler.xml and when I reopened the project a new compiler.xml was generated and the project compiled without any issues.